# Sharing c# variables between methods?

Tags: c#

I have different methods how can I share the `strHeaderFileName` (etc) variables between them?
For example I need `strHeaderFileName` in the btnSave_Click method.

```
protected void multiFileUpload_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
{
    // No Loop needed multiFileUpload_FileUploaded will be called for each file uploaded
    var strHeaderFileName = e.File.FileName;
    // Use the filename as the Header Name
    var strHeaderName = strHeaderFileName.Replace(".jpg", "");
    // allow Underscore characters in FileName to become Spaces in the Display Name.
    strHeaderName = strHeaderName.Replace("_", " ");
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use the same strHeaderFileName value here?
}
```

Comment: Read about [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173118(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @GrantWinney I normally would put them at the top of the class but didn't want to scroll 1000 lines of code to place them up there.. lol was hoping there was another way.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "I didn't want to scroll" as a reason for not defining variables at class level before

Comment: @JoJo: If your class has 1000 lines of code then that is a problem in and of itself, unrelated to the class-level variables.  It sounds like some of this functionality should be refactored into other objects.  In any event, having to scroll to the top of the file *once* is hardly a reason not to do something.  Your entire application isn't going to fit into a single viewer window...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options.  Since these methods are event handlers and aren't directly invoked, the best approach here is likely to make the variable class-level members:

```
private string strHeaderFileName;

protected void multiFileUpload_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
{
    strHeaderFileName = e.File.FileName;
    // etc.
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here you can access strHeaderFileName
}
```

As class-level members, they will be accessible by *any* method in that class.  (Make sure you keep them `private` or other objects will be able to access them too, which you probably don't want in this case.)  And they will exist for the lifetime of any given instance of that class.

**Also note** that this looks like ASP.NET, which behaves a little differently in terms of class instances than things like WinForms.  Any given instance of a `Page` doesn't persist between requests.  So if you set the value in one handler, display the page again, and then invoke another handler the value won't be there anymore.  This is because the class instance for each `Page` is created per-request and then destroyed after the response.

To persist across page requests, you'd need to keep the value somewhere else.  For example, if it needs to live during the scope of that user's session then you can put it in session state:

```
protected void multiFileUpload_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
{
    Session["strHeaderFileName"] = e.File.FileName;
    // etc.
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here you can access Session["strHeaderFileName"]
}
```

Depending on the scope in which the value needs to persist, you could also put it on the page, in a cookie, in a database, some caching mechanism, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate option in this case seems to be: to use an instance field:

```
string strHeaderFileName;

protected void multiFileUpload_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    strHeaderFileName = e.File.FileName;
    // ...
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // can use strHeaderFileName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would make them member variables instead of local variables, e.g.

```
string strHeaderFileName;
string strHeaderName;

    protected void multiFileUpload_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
{
    // No Loop needed multiFileUpload_FileUploaded will be called for each file uploaded
    strHeaderFileName = e.File.FileName;
    // Use the filename as the Header Name
    strHeaderName = strHeaderFileName.Replace(".jpg", "");
    // allow Underscore characters in FileName to become Spaces in the Display Name.
    strHeaderName = strHeaderName.Replace("_", " ");
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // strHeaderFileName is now accessible here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `var strHeaderFileName` as a member of your class.
So if this is a page for example

```
class Page
{
  private string strHeaderFileName;
 protected void multiFileUpload_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
    {
        // No Loop needed multiFileUpload_FileUploaded will be called for each file uploaded
        strHeaderFileName = e.File.FileName;
        // Use the filename as the Header Name
        var strHeaderName = strHeaderFileName.Replace(".jpg", "");
        // allow Underscore characters in FileName to become Spaces in the Display Name.
        strHeaderName = strHeaderName.Replace("_", " ");
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use the same strHeaderFileName value here?
       someFunctionUses(strHeaderFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: code snippets are only for browser runnable code, it wont work for c#